# Observer pattern using a set of observers and delegated properties

Tags: observer-pattern, kotlin

The idea is to implement the observer pattern, with a separate notification method for each observed property of the observed object. Let me start with a simplified use case:

```
class Point {
    val observers: ObserverSet<PointObserver>()
    val x by observers.observe(0f, PointObserver::xChanged)
    val y by observers.observe(0f, PointObserver::yChanged)
}

interface PointObserver {
    fun xChanged(old: Float, new: Float)
    fun yChanged(old: Float, new: Float)
}

class PointView(point: Point) {
    init {
        point.observers.add(object : PointObserver {
            override fun xChanged(old: Float, new: Float) { ... }
            override fun yChanged(old: Float, new: Float) { ... }
        })
    }
}
```

I'm new to Kotlin, so I'd like some feedback on the following implementation:

```
import kotlin.properties.ReadWriteProperty
import kotlin.reflect.KProperty

/**
 * A set of observers for a particular object, to easily implement the Observer Pattern without needing inheritance.
 *
 * This can be made a public property of the object. Call [observe] to create delegated properties for each property
 * that observers need to be notified about.
 *
 * @param O The type of the observers, typically an interface.
 */
class ObserverSet<O> {

    private val observers = mutableSetOf<O>()
    private val properties = mutableListOf<ObservedProperty<*>>()

    /**
     * Sets whether an observer is present in the set. If the observer was actually added to the set, its notification
     * methods will be called with the current value of the property.
     *
     * @param observer The observer.
     * @param present If true, the observer will be added to the set if not already there. If false, the observer will
     *   be removed from the set if it's there.
     */
    fun toggle(observer: O, present: Boolean) {
        if (present) {
            val wasPresent = observer in observers
            observers.add(observer)
            if (!wasPresent) {
                init(observer)
            }
        } else {
            observers.remove(observer)
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates a delegate property with a callback that notifies each observer.
     *
     * @param V The type of the property.
     * @param initialValue The initial value of the property.
     * @param onChanged Function on the [O] interface that will be called with the old and new value after the
     *   property has been changed.
     */
    fun <V> observe(initialValue: V, onChanged: O.(old: V, new: V) -> Unit): ReadWriteProperty<Any?, V> {
        val property = ObservedProperty(initialValue, onChanged)
        properties.add(property)
        return property
    }

    private fun init(observer: O) {
        properties.forEach { property ->
            property.initObserver(observer)
        }
    }

    private inner class ObservedProperty<V>(initialValue: V, private val onChanged: O.(old: V, new: V) -> Unit) :
            ReadWriteProperty<Any?, V> {

        private var value = initialValue

        override fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): V {
            return value
        }

        override fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: V) {
            val oldValue = this.value
            this.value = value
            observers.forEach { observer ->
                observer.onChanged(oldValue, value)
            }
        }

        fun initObserver(observer: O) {
            observer.onChanged(value, value)
        }
    }
}
```

(The `toggle` method is the only one I need right now; regular `add` and `remove` could of course be implemented as well.)

I'm mainly interested in efficiency considerations, ways to make this more general, and following Kotlin best practices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You don't need a `wasPresent` variable. `MutableSet.add` returns `true` if the `element` was added to the set:

   ```
   if (observers.add(observer)) {
       init(observer)
   }
   ```
2. Sometimes in Kotlin you don't have to declare temporary variables so that you can do something with a return value before returning it. e.g.:

   ```
   return ObservedProperty(initialValue, onChanged).apply { properties.add(this) }
   ```

   Unfortunately this can sometimes look a bit strange using `this`, etc. but in Kotlin 1.1 you can use bound callable references:

   ```
   return ObservedProperty(initialValue, onChanged).apply(properties::add)
   ```
3. You might want to take a look at [Delegates.observable - stdlib - Kotlin Programming Language](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.properties/-delegates/observable.html) which you may be able to reuse to improve and reduce your code.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware of #1. I learned about #2 since I posted this, and though I like the idiom in general, I probably wouldn't use it here. I was aware of #3, and indeed it originally formed the basis of my own implementation; I don't remember exactly why I ditched it. Maybe just for educational value.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to post a slightly different opinion; the previous answer is perfectly sensible but they aren't the changes I'd make.

1. I'd encourage you to use the `+=` operator instead of `add`. The reason being it gives you a kind of duck-typing with collections: your code (at a source compatibility layer) stops caring about the specific implementation of the *add like thing*, and instead asks if the type implements a fairly common operator. The single most obvious advantage here is that it allows you to switch from `val mutableCollection` to `var immutableCollection` completely without (source-compatability) issue.

   > this also negates your ability to use `add` for its return value, since `operator +=` is defined to return `Unit` (`void`), so you'll need to formalize your membership info (`wasPresent`) in a side channel.
2. I don't know how much advantage there is to a unified 2-method `PointObserver` interface, at least as anything other than an implementation detail. You might consider dropping that interface in favor of `onXChanged` and `onYChanged` (and possibly `onXOrYChanged`).
3. You might also use a sealed class to implement your point observer, rather than an interface.

combining suggestions 2 & 3:

```
class Point {
  val observers: ObserverSet<PointObserver>()
  val x by observers.observe<XChanged>(0f)
  val y by observers.observe<YChanged>(0f)

  fun onXChanged(handler: (old: Float, new: Float) -> Unit) = observers += XChanged(handler)
  fun onYChanged(handler: (old: Float, new: Float) -> Unit) = observers += YChanged(handler)
}

sealed class PointObserver()
class XChanged(val handler: (Float, Float) -> Unit): PointObserver()
class YChanged(val handler: (Float, Float) -> Unit): PointObserver()

class PointView(point: Point) {
  init {
    point.onXChanged { old, new -> ... }
    point.onYChanged { old, new -> ... }
  }
}
```

which would require an implementation change:

```
fun <reified T: PointObserver> ObservableSet<PointObserver>.observe(default: Float)
    = ObservedProperty(initialValue) { it is T }

private inner class ObservedProperty<V>(private var value: V, private val handlerFilter: (PointObserver) -> Boolean) :
        ReadWriteProperty<Any?, V> {

    override fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>) = value

    override fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, newValue: V) {
        val oldValue = this.value
        this.value = newValue
        observers.filter(handlerFilter).forEach { observer ->
            when(observer){
               is XChanged -> observer.handler(oldValue, newValue)
               is YChanged -> observer.handler(oldValue, newValue)
            }
        }
    }

    fun initObserver(observer: O) {
        observer.onChanged(value, value)
    }
}
```

---

Note however that this should really only be used for instructional purposes, there are plenty of libraries out there that have built-in observer pattern implementations, not the least of which is guava. You're likely much better off using one of those libraries than suffering from the [inner-platform effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed review. #1, using `+=` instead of `add` on sets is a good suggestion. As to #2 and #3, of course the `Point` was a simplified example; the real use case has at least 5 observed properties. The whole point of this implementation was that I don't need to define both a property `x` and a function `onXChanged` for each of them. Decoupling the observers for each property into a separate interface makes sense in some situations, but in my case it's more convenient to have one bundle (easier to unregister the observer).